# Using an image as a background in bootsrap 4 card

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to achieve this design which shown in the image here.
[image]

In bootsrap 4, it is just a group of card with the class card-img-overlay in it. 
The problem is that the height of the card depends on the height of the image

(I suppose) making the height of the card shorter or taller, depending on the

Image. How can I solve this so that all the cards which has a background

image have the same height? Also how can I put the image inside the card

without losing its aspect ratio? (The example image shows that the background

image inside of the card. Instead of trying to cover the whole card, It just

crops the piece of the image and put it inside.)

```html
<div class="card text-white style="width: 10rem;">
<img class="card-img" src="/images/1.jpg" alt="Card image">
<div class="card-img-overlay text-white d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
   <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
   <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a 
      natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
   </p>
   <p class="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a> 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just specify the height using the sizing utilities? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/sizing/

Comment: I did this as you suggested by setting a fixed height to the parent and set the h-100 in the card class which is a descendant. It did fill the height relative to the parent, but background image did not fill the entire card class. Maybe this means the height of the card doesn't depend on the height of the image, but it is still not solving my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the size of all images by adding the parameters of the image class in CSS like this:

```
.card-img{
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: I set the height of the card-img to 100% and it solved my problem.